# How to handle negative input data in deep belief networks

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, rbm, dbn

In my data, I have a column with negative and positive values. Here negative value means how much some things are missing and positive values means unexpected additional things and 0 means neutral which is always expected value. So how can I use this column of data as input for deep belief networks. Can I input negative numbers as input in deep belief networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can consider two things. Firstly, there should not be an underlying problem inputting negative values - is there are specific reason you question this?

More importantly if you want, you can pre-process your dataset, or do it during input. There are many activation functions you can use that result in absolute values, like something as simple as the sigmoid function. There is nothing wrong with activating input values, in fact its recommended.

Comment: I have never seen any example or read an article that deals with negative input values for deep belief networks. So I was wondering if I have to do any preprocessing or if I have to handle negative inputs in a special way. Thats why I posted this question.

Comment: Well in most situations you should standardise values anyway by either using an activation function or dividing them (if they all are of the same type). Either way, negative values should not make a difference. Hope this helps.